# Google Scripts or VBA - Insert rows upon entering input value (Excel)

Tags: javascript, vba, excel, google-sheets

I am using Google Sheets with Google Scripts and I want to insert rows upon user entering a number, without needing to run the code on the script editor. So, if I change the value on the selected cell, the code should run automatically, which is not happening. This is my code so far:

```
function PopulateColumn() { 
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
for (i = 1; i<=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(9,2).getValue(); i++) {
sheet.insertRowsAfter(11, SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(9,2).getValue())
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(i+10,1).setValue('Arrangement ' + i + ':')
}
}
```

This is working without the automatic part but instead of inserting the rows, its overwriting the data that's already written on those cells. I want to maintain that data...

Another way that I'm trying is to use VBA editor with Excel on the computer, but also with similar problems. If there is something written than "arrangements" on the desired cells, it does not run; if there are already "arrangements", it keeps counting. That's not what I want... If I choose "3" and then "5", it should display only the arrangements from 1 to 5 and not from 1 to 8. And it should insert the rows without losing the data that is written before.

> @Tom's code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim i As Long
Dim StartingRow As Long
Dim StartingArrangement As Long

If Not Intersect(Target, Me.Cells(1, 2)) Is Nothing Then
    With Me
        StartingRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

        If StartingRow < 3 Then
            StartingRow = 2
        Else
            StartingArrangement = CLng(Trim(Replace(Replace(.Cells(StartingRow, 1), "Arrangement ", vbNullString), ":", vbNullString)))
        End If

        For i = 1 To .Cells(1, 2).Value2
            .Cells(StartingRow, 1).Offset(i, 0).Value2 = "Arrangement " & StartingArrangement + i & ":"
        Next i
    End With
End If
End Sub
```

Can somebody help me please? Don't know nothing about both of these languages!

Comment: You could do this with google scripts. No need for Excel

Comment: In Javascript? How can I get the value from the cell?

Comment: I've never worked with Google sheets so have no idea if it's possible but I would take @Tom word for it. In VBA, just use the excel range.formula .. i.e. `Thisworkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Formula = "=SUM(A2:A5)"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both take an input in cell `B1` and populate column `A`.

Google Script method:
Select Tools -> Script Editor
N.B. I haven't updated the GS script after comments as there doesn't seem to be interest in it

```
function PopulateColumn() { 
  for (i = 1; i<=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(1,2).getValue(); i++) {
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(i,1).setValue('Arrangement ' + i + ':')
  }
}
```

VBA method: In the VBA Editor on the left hand side underneath 'Microsoft Excel Objects' you will find the sheet objects. Paste this into the sheet that you want it to populate

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim i As Long
    Dim StartingRow As Long
    Dim StartingArrangement As Long

    If Not Intersect(Target, Me.Cells(1, 2)) Is Nothing Then
        With Me
            StartingRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

            If StartingRow < 3 Then
                StartingRow = 2
            Else
                StartingArrangement = CLng(Trim(Replace(Replace(.Cells(StartingRow, 1), "Arrangement ", vbNullString), ":", vbNullString)))
            End If

            For i = 1 To .Cells(1, 2).Value2
                .Cells(StartingRow, 1).Offset(i, 0).Value2 = "Arrangement " & StartingArrangement + i & ":"
            Next i
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: VBA: Thank for your help but I don't want to overwrite the data when I write on the cells. How can I insert the rows? And can I run the code instantly upon choosing the number, instead of clicking on "Run" on the editor every time?

GS: Says it cant read "range" from undefined (line 2)

Comment: I've updated it to remove the events. GS will say that when you try to debug an Event

Comment: JS: Thank you but overwrites data on the cells, how can I insert the rows instead of overwriting data thats written on those cells?

Comment: VBA: Can't understand what you mean about going in the sheet object... What should I do in the VBA editor? I had never worked with this, sorry for being so annoying!

Comment: Ignore that bit that was for an Event driven base. Stick the code in a Module (you may have to insert one) and click run

Comment: Just did it, still overwrites instead of inserting and I need to click run instead of automatically running upon value changing... Do you know how to fix this?

Comment: I hadn't updated it to ignore that. Give it a try now. Haven't bothered to updated the GS as you don't seem interested in it

Comment: VBA: Thank you very much for your continuous help but it does not run automatically upon entering the value, I need to click "run" on the vba editor; and keeps adding if I change the value and run again. If I firstly enter "3" and then "5", it should display only 5 arrangements, from 1 to 5!

Comment: Think there was a miscommunication somewhere as it did this automatically when I was talking about the sheet object

Comment: GS: Actually maybe it would be the best solution because I will need to work with the column next to the dynamically created cells! I'm looking for a way to insert the rows without overwriting and to trigger the function upon entering the value on the cell